# Number of parameters for discrete Bayes network?

Tags: bayesian-network

Suppose $X_1, ..., X_n$ are $d$-ary discrete random variables which are part of a Bayes network, in which $X_i$ has $n_i$ parents.  What is the number of parameters for the Bayes network?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

For one random variable with k parents the number of parameters = $$ d \cdot d^k $$
If you need independent parameters: $$ (d-1) \cdot d^k $$